# Destacar dados Filtro

Tags: php, filtro

Estou com um problema em destacar dados de um filtro.
Ou seja eu faço o filtro e mostro muitas datas.

```
<?php
   include("conectar.php");

$quantidade = 1;
$pagina = (isset($_GET ['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;
$inicio = ($quantidade * $pagina) - $quantidade;
$sql = "select * from tb_detalhe_trabalhador inner join tb_trabalhador on      tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_trabalhador.id inner join tb_equipamentos on  tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_equipamentos.id ORDER BY tb_trabalhador.id asc LIMIT $inicio,  $quantidade";
$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
    echo "<table>"; 

    echo  "<tr><td>Nome:</td>";
    echo "<td>".$exibe["Nome"]."</td></tr>";

    echo  "<tr><td>Morada:</td>"; echo "<td>";
    if ($exibe['Morada']){ echo $exibe['Morada'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

    echo "<tr><td>Tipo:</td>";echo"<td>";
    if($exibe['Tipo']){ echo $exibe['Tipo'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

    echo "<tr><td>Email:</td>"; echo "<td>";
    if($exibe['Email']){ echo $exibe['Email'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

    echo "<tr><td>Alvara Numero:</td>";echo"<td>";
    if($exibe['AlvaraNumero']){ echo $exibe['AlvaraNumero'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo " </td></tr>";

     echo "<tr><td>Alvara Validade:</td>";echo"<td>";
     if($exibe['AlvaraValidade']){ echo $exibe['AlvaraValidade'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";
```

A query ainda é bastante grande e gostava de destacar todas as datas que estejam ultrapassadas com uma cor ou algo assim.
Consigo fazer isso com o PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você usará PHP para verificar se a data já passou (você não esclareceu onde está a data a ser verificada, estou supondo que é em "AlvaraValidade"):

```
if (strtotime($exibe['AlvaraValidade']) < time()) {
    // Coloca uma cor diferente
}
```

Sendo específico para o seu caso, colocando a cor Vermelha na data:

```
echo "<tr><td>Alvara Validade:</td>";
echo"<td>";
if ($exibe['AlvaraValidade']) { 
    if (strtotime($exibe['AlvaraValidade']) < time()) {
        echo '<span style="color:red">'.$exibe['AlvaraValidade'].'</span>';
    } else {
        echo $exibe['AlvaraValidade'];
    }
} else { 
    echo 'N/D';
} 
echo "</td></tr>";
```

Tem um detalhe importante: Você estará usando a função strtotime() para transformar uma string em timestamp. Essa string precisa estar no formato que geralmente está no banco de dados, que é por exemplo: 2014-03-24 13:21:00 ou somente a data 2013-03-24, então ele consegue comparar com a data atual que é obtida com time() em um inteiro timestamp. Se a data estiver no formato brasileiro por exemplo, você precisa mudá-la para o formato d-m-Y

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode colocar a condicional direto na consulta SQL, que irá abstrair um pouco mais sua lógica:

SQL:

```
SELECT 
    id, nome, morada, etc, IF (datacadastro < '2014-02-01', 'ultrapassada', '') AS ultrapassada
FROM
    tb_detalhe_trabalhador 
    INNER JOIN tb_trabalhador on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_trabalhador.id 
    INNER JOIN tb_equipamentos on  tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_equipamentos.id
```

PHP:

```
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
    echo("
        <table>
            <tr class='{$exibe['datacadastro']}' >
                <td >{$exibe['datacadastro']}</td>
                <td>{$exibe['morada']}</td>
                <td>{$exibe['nome']}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>"
    );
}
```

CSS:

```
tr.ultrapassada {
    background: red;
}
```

Neste exemplo rústico, todas as linhas com datas antes de 2014/fevereiro serão destacadas em vermelho.

Outras opções poderiam ser (no banco de dados):

```
IF (DATEDIFF(NOW(), c.datacadastro) > 30, 'mais-de-30-dias', '') AS maisDe30
IF (DATEDIFF(NOW(), c.datacadastro) < 7, 'ultimos-7-dias', '') AS ultimos7dias
```

Além disso, colocando as condicionais no banco de dados, o desempenho será muitíssimo mais rápido do que no PHP.